# How to set Javascript style.tranform="scale" dynamically

Tags: javascript, transform, mermaid

I have declared a variable `var scale=0.8` in a script on the body of my html and when i resize a graph made by mermaid i update the scale accordingly, for example

```
<script>
var scale=0.8;
DeployGraph(); 

function toggleZoomScreen(mode){
if (mode == 1){
 scale+=0.1;
//  document.body.style.zoom=scale.toString()+"%";
}
else if (mode == 2){
scale-=0.1;
//  document.body.style.zoom=scale.toString()+"%";
}
var mer = document.getElementById("mermaid");
mer.style.transform= "scale("+scale+","+scale+")";
} 
</script>
```

I want to somehow keep the value of the variable so that every time I refresh, DeployGraph is called and the graph gets resized in that same scale value. DeployGraph is declared on the head of the html, not the body.
Can this be done?

I tried creating a different variable in the head and update it everytime the scale value changes, then in the DeployGraph I use
`element.style.transform= "scale("+scale+","+scale+")";` where element = document.getElementById("mermaid");
However, the value is always the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't persist variables across page refreshes.

What you need to do is store the value you need in the browser and check for it once the page loads.

You can do this using [URL search parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams), [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) or [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

When using local storage, you could do the following:

```js
// On document load, after initialising the scale variable
scale = window.localStorage.getItem('scale') || 0.8; // add || 0.8 in case value is undefined

// In toggleZoomScreen
function toggleZoomScreen(mode){
  if (mode == 1){
    scale+=0.1;
  }
  else if (mode == 2){
    scale-=0.1;
  }

  // Update the value in local storage
  window.localStorage.setItem('scale', scale);

  var mer = document.getElementById("mermaid");
  mer.style.transform= "scale("+scale+","+scale+")";
}
```

Comment: When I try the local storage solution, I get the message "Unable to get property 'getItem' of undefined or null reference". The html is not running directly in a browser, it is used to show a graph generated by mermaid inside a control of an ERP program. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: If it's not running in a browser none of the approaches will work, but the concept you need remains the same. You can check if the erm program exposes some kind of API similar to local storage or cookies.